# Where to keep dictionaries in app using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, legacy-code

I have a legacy code, and I have a problem with reconstructor it.

At start of my application I load from `WCF` to property on `App` (this is `SL` application) list of users.

Then every control (for sending emails, view calendar and assigning tasks) use this property as

```
(App.Current as App).Users
```

Now, I'm trying to create Unit Test for one of controls that use this lists, and I'm stuck.

Should I make a Constructor Injection(I'm using Unity) with `App` as parameter? Or maybe introduce some class to hold this list?

Comment: Jimmy, you made great job. But now I'm focusing on good practices. You got great feedback from other users(5 votes including mine). I changed my choise, and I checked your answer, but bounty goes to @one.beat.consumer who gave us (you and me) nice feedback. Thanks once again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated with OP's implementation as the pseudocode was incomplete.**

I propose create an interface for all your application services

Inject IApplicationService to your modules.

You can use this interface for all the services the application provides(probably you will need more). Mock the interface for the unit tests

**OP's implemantation**

```
 public interface IApplicationService
    {
        List<User> Users{get;set;}
    }

    public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
    {
        public List<User> Users
        {
            get { return (App.Current as App).Users; }
            set { (App.Current as App).Users = value; }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : UserControl
    {
        readonly IApplicationService _applicationService
        public MainWindow(IApplicationService applicationService)
        {
            _applicationService=applicationService;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you look at my answer? I see that you wpf man, so maybe that's why there is need to change something (like Windows, or App.Current as App). And some piece of code need to change (like pubic property on the interface or lack of setter in implementation. And the most important - I took ApplicationService out from MainWindow

Comment: @user278618 and Jimmy - solid answer no downvote, though a couple things need correction - ex. your class does not implement the interface properly (ex. property name mismatch) and there are some syntax errors. I posted my own answer with several improvements on top of these corrections.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a wrapper class that will expose the list of users. In production code this class will just be a wrapper around your App.Current property and it can be injected in the constructor trough Unity.

In your Unit Tests you can easily mock the App parameter and pass it when constructing a new SUT.

Something like:

```
public interface IUserList
{
   List<User> Users { get; }
}

public class SUT
{
   private IUserList UserList { get; set; }

   public SUT(IUserList userList)
   {
     this.UserList = userList;
   }
}

public class AppUserList : IUserList
{
   public List<User> Users
   {
      get
      {
         return ((App)App.Current).Users;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Silverlight there is an extension model called [Application Extension Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833084%28VS.95%29.aspx#accessing_extension_services_from_application_code).

For infrastructure purposes that might be a better alternative than adding properties to your app class and casting `App.Current`back and forth.

Downside of that model is the creation of a singleton you would have to initialize for your unit tests. It would also hide the dependency on `Users` in your consuming classes.

Your users seem to be just data. Making that data an ambient context which can be accessed and edited everywhere in your application will bite you. You don't know who does what with that data and when he does it. This is like a session state.

So making the dependency on your data explicit would be a first step to be able to track abuse of that data.

If it makes sense to you to create a "data holder object" that has a property for `Users` or directly inject that data into your consumers is up to you. If there is more data than just `Users`it is tempting to put all of them into the same central data store object, even if your specific consumers don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy's answer is great, but can be provide quite a bit, and some errors fixed. Differences are explained at the bottom below the code/instructions:

---

**Create a public interface: `IUserService`**

```
public interface IUserService
{       
    // Implemented functionality as methods where possible for better
    // extendability (like IoC)
    IEnumerable<User> Users();

    // Add any other user service stuff as you see fit.
    void AddUser(User user);
}
```

**Write a `UserService` that implements `IUserService`**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    // If you need DI for this service, follow the same pattern of using 
    // fields and controller injection. I left examples in comment below.

    // private readonly IRepository _repository;

    // Constructor is unnecessary if you do not need DI example.
    public UserService(/* IRepository repository */) 
    {
        // _repository = repository;
    }

    // Methods
    public IEnumerable<User> Users()
    {
        return ((App)App.Current).Users;
    }
    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        ((App)App.Current).Users.Add(user);
    }

}
```

**Inject `IUserService` into classes via their Constructor**

In this case your MainWindow as an example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : UserControl
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public MainWindow(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    // Example method consuming the service
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _userService.Users();
    }
}
```

---

#### Differences:

1. Separate your User Services from a central Application Service

   Better modularity. In addition I use an `IApplicationService` for more central/global data like Api Keys, Timeouts, cleanup, DB prepping, etc.
2. Return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`

   This is just a golden rule of thumb for keeping things dry and not imposing hard instantiations on your consuming classes. Refactoring is easier/safer, and your code more extensible.
3. Use methods instead of properties

   This is preference, but I think it smart in a service layer to use methods where possible so that you can introduce filters and overloads or continue to use dependency injection - for example, you could add `GetUsers(string lastName)`, `GetUsers(string lastName, string firstName)` and maintain a clean interface for your consuming classes.
4. Cast `App.Current` without the `as` keyword

   This is a good practice because using the `as` keyword means when the cast fails it will return null, rather than throw an exception. I prefer the exception because 99% of the time, if your cast fails, your next operations will too. :)

Enjoy!